# map an array in componentDidMount and render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i'm traying to map an array in componentDidMount and render it but it doesn't show anything
can anyone help me please?

```
componentDidMount() {
  baseUrl
      .get("/api/v1/bases")
        .then((response) => {
          const data = response.data.data.data.data;
          console.log(data)
             const items = data.map((item) => {
               return (
                 <div>
                   <tr key={item.id}>
                     <td scope="row">{item.id}</td>
                     <td scope="row">{item.name}</td>
                     <td scope="row">
                       <button className="btn btn btn-outline-danger m-1 my-2 my-sm-0">
                         حذف
                       </button>
                       <Link
                         id={item.id}
                         to={`/Bases/edit/${item.id}`}
                         className="btn btn btn-outline-warning m-1 my-2 my-sm-0"
                       >
                         ویرایش
                       </Link>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                 </div>
               );
             });
          })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

and i am trying to render it like this code inside table

```
</tr>
          {this.items}
        </tbody>
```

it is just part of code

Comment: Not a react expert. But I would do this in the render method.

Comment: i did it to, still the same

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note: `const items = data.map....` <-- the API response / data is mapped and stored in `items`. But, this `items` is [block-scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). As [described in below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70903894/13658816), the `items` may be set-to-state.

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` / `useEffect` are used to hook into the component's lifecycle.
They are not meant to render/return any JSX elements.
You could transform/map your data within `componentDidMount` and update the local component state which can then be used in `render` to display your data

```
class Component {
  state = [];

  async componentDidMount() {
    const items = await fetch()

    const mappedItems = items.map(item => item)

    this.setState(items)
  }

  render() {
    <ul>{this.state.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        {item}
      </li>
    ))}
    </ul>

  }
}
```

Comment: `const mappedItems = items.map(item => item)` <-- did you intend to use `mappedItems` on the 'setState'?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You have to use the components state. Just updated my answer

Comment: i didn't understand you mean.
but i did this inside a render method but it didn't show either

Answer (score 1):

Just call your API in `ComponenDidMount` lifecycle and display your data into `render function`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: i have problem with displaying it 
i did it with a render method but nothing displayed